# Duda al crear tabla en SQL con llave foránea

Tags: sql, oracle

tengo la siguiente tabla en SQL:

```
create table artista(
   id number(10) primary key,
   nombre varchar(50)
);
```

Quiero crear una tabla que represente una relación N:N que va de la tabla artista a la tabla artista y la estoy haciendo de esta forma:

```
create table similar(
    art1 number(10),
    art2 number(10),
    foreign key (art1,art2) references artista,
    primary key(art1,art2)
);
```

pero me da el siguiente error al ejecutar:

```
Informe de error - ORA-02256: el número de columnas de referencia debe coincidir con las columnas a las que se hace referencia
02256. 00000 -  "number of referencing columns must match referenced columns"
*Cause:    The number of columns in the foreign-key referencing list is not
           equal to the number of columns in the referenced list.
*Action:   Make sure that the referencing columns match the referenced
           columns.
```

¿Alguien me podía echar un cable para solucionar el error?

Gracias, un saludo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando usas una llave foránea, esta debe referenciar TODOS los campos de la llave primaria correspondiente. Nada más, nada menos.

En tu caso, la llave primaria sólo tiene un campo. En la llave foránea pones dos. Para lo que intentas, que es resolver una relación M-N, deberías tener DOS fk, una sobre cada campo ID, referenciando la llave primaria correspondiente para cada registro en la tabla Artista.

Es clave entender aquí cómo se está resolviendo la relación M-N: un registro en `similar` tiene dos tablas de las que hereda (ambas vienen a ser `Artista`) y de cada una recibe un id. No significa que con un fk se haga todo; significa que de cada una se hace un fk recibiendo la llave primaria. Si tienes tu diagrama Entidad-Relación, con seguridad tendrás dos relaciones 1-N entre estas dos tablas y es por eso que terminas usando dos `constraints`.

De paso, una sugerencia adicional y es nombrar tus constraints. De esta forma, puedes manipularlos más fácil después (si no los nombras, el motor les pone nombres aleatorios del estilo SYS_i348753954 y modificarlos es más dispendioso.

Tu definición podría ser algo así:

```
create table similar(
    art1 number(10),
    art2 number(10),
    CONSTRAINT fk_artista_1
        FOREIGN KEY (art1)
        REFERENCES artista(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_artista_2
        FOREIGN KEY (art2)
        REFERENCES artista(id),
    CONSTRAINT similar_pk PRIMARY KEY (art1, art2)
);
```

Un SQLfiddle para jugar con esta sugerencia, ponerle datos y demás: [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1a6e1/8/4)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta separar las `constraints` asi:

```
create table similar(
    art1 number(10),
    art2 number(10),
    foreign key (art1) references artista(id),
    foreign key (art2) references artista(id),
    primary key(art1,art2)
);
```